# How to get List value from map object

Tags: java, list, hashmap

I have object value called "mastervalue" from my hashmap. The mastervalue contain ques_id as key, and an array contain score and answer as value. How to get value of the array only(the score and answer) and return as List.

```
String maprule = "department == '2' && topic == '1'";

mastervalue = (Map<String, List<String>>) map_master.get(maprule);
System.out.println(mastervalue);
```

mastervalue print out :
{10359=[4, 1], 10365=[1, 1], 10364=[1, 1], 10363=[4, 1], 10362=[3, 1], 10369=[1, 1], 10368=[5, 1]}

Comment: you want the the list of all the value objects?

Comment: yes, i want to get the value of the list in the object.

Comment: Also note that Map.values() return a non serializable collection. Rogue's answer below is spot on.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Okay:

```
public <T> List<T> getValues(Map<?, T> map) {
    return new ArrayList<>(map.values());
}
```

Inlined:

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<>(map_master.values());
```

Or using the method:

```
List<List<String>> list = getValues(map_master);
```

Alternatively, if you want to put all the values of all the lists into one, just iterate:

```
List<String> total = new ArrayList<>();
for (List<String> lis : map_master.values()) {
    total.addAll(lis);
}
```

And with Java 8 streams:

```
List<String> total = map_master.values().stream()
                            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

For Koltin users here is the way:

```
val listOfObjects = List<Object>?.stream()?.flatMap { obj: Collection<Object> -> obj.stream() }
                ?.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Generic way:

```
fun <T: Any> listList(list: List<List<KClass<T>>>) = list.stream().flatMap { obj: Collection<*> -> obj.stream() }.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin there is a shortcut:

```
map.values.flatten()
```

As the doc states:

> Returns a single list of all elements from all collections in the given collection.